# Nmr installation on ServiceMix 4

Tags: spring, esb, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to install NMR reading Fuse ESB [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/Nmr-Component.html), but what I don't really understand it that line inside camel-context.xml.

```
 <import resource="classpath:org/apache/servicemix/camel/nmr/camel-nmr.xml" />
```

where exactly is that resource? It's not inside my maven repository. I was also looking inside ServiceMix directory system and libraries and I couldn't find it. All I Know is fact that without this import my service is not starting and it's still in waiting mode. Maybe it's a stupid question, but I will be glad for any kind of help.

Comment: I think that files is inside some servicemix-camel JAR

Comment: And btw any reason why using an old ESB like Fuse ESB 7.1 ?

Comment: What do you mean? Unfortunately I've to use this version of servicemix and I need to use some component to send requests through camel contexts. I would like to use direct:vm, but I've camel 2.4 so my last chance is NMR.